# willRotateToInterfaceOrientation gets called after device get rotated

Tags: ios, ios7, rotation

I have a some code in the `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method. But it gets called after orientation gets changed.

And I want this method to be called before orientation gets changed.

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
 //some code   
}
```

anyone know why this happens...

Comment: The device only knows to rotate the orientation after the user's actually rotated the device, so there's no way to anticipate the orientation will change until the user actually rotates the device.

Comment: But in documentation support, they written willRotateToInterfaceOrientation() gets called before orientation changed...

Comment: Yes, before the interface orientation changes, not before the device orientation changes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but found a way around. Just start listening to device orientation events:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                         selector: @selector( detectOrientation )
                                             name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                           object: nil];
```

Your handler (`detectOrientation` in the example above) will be called **before** the `-willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientationduration:` method, thus also before the screen is rendered in the new orientation.

Just pay attention that every call to `beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications` must match a call to `endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications` ([as noted in the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIDevice/beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications)). So if you call the first at `-viewDidLoad`, don't forget to call the latter at `dealloc`.

Another thing to mind is that this method turns on the accelerometer hardware, so your application might consume more battery while it is still effective (that is, until you call `endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications`).